# How to speed up the sorting algorithm based on Array.Sort() for a 2-dimensional array of object values (.NET)?

Tags: .net, arrays, algorithm, sorting, unboxing

We have a two-dimensional array of Objects. Generally every item is a common value type like Int32 or Decimal, and one column of the array contains values of the same type. Our array can contain about a million rows, and we need to sort it.

To make it fast, we use a special algorithm based on so called row map, when every item of the row map array contains the index of the array row to display in the specific position. We do not swap array rows while sorting - we just sort the row map array using our custom comparer.

The main part of the sorting algorithm looks like this:

```cs
RowNavigatorMapComparer myRowNavigatorMapComparer = new RowNavigatorMapComparer(this, myGroupAndSortData, isGrouping);
RowNavigatorMapItem[] map = RowNavigatorMapItem.FromRowNavigatorArray(fRowsMap, rowIndex, rowCount);
Array.Sort(map, myRowNavigatorMapComparer);
```

`RowNavigatorMapComparer` implements `IComparer<RowNavigatorMapItem>`, and two array array values are compared inside its `int Compare(RowNavigatorMapItem x, RowNavigatorMapItem y)` implementation like this:

```cs
return ManagerCompare.CompareObjects(cellX.Value, cellY.Value);
```

, where ManagerCompare is implemented this way:

```cs
public class ManagerCompare
{
    private ManagerCompare(){}

    public static int CompareObjects(object valueX, object valueY)
    {
        IComparable myValueX = valueX as IComparable;
        IComparable myValueY = valueY as IComparable;
        if(myValueX == null)
        {
            if(myValueY == null)
                return 0;
            return -1;
        }
        if(myValueY == null)
            return 1;

        Type myTypeX = myValueX.GetType();
        Type myTypeY = myValueY.GetType();
        if(myTypeX != myTypeY)
            return string.CompareOrdinal(myTypeX.Name, myTypeY.Name); 

        return  myValueX.CompareTo(myValueY);
    }
}
```

We do not like the performance of the whole construction described above and would like to speed up it dramatically. We know that calling `Array.Sort(map, myRowNavigatorMapComparer)` takes 98% of time for the test random contents of the array. And if we return -1 instead of `ManagerCompare.CompareObjects(cellX.Value, cellY.Value)` just to estimate the speed if all items have been already sorted, the total time reduces up to ten times. So, it seems, the main problem in the Array.Sort() implementation, i.e. how it moves the data in the array. Is there any way to replace it with something more effective?

Another point to consider could be using hard-coded comparison algorithms for every column of our target array if we know the type of the values stored in the column. For instance, if a column contains integer values, we could use the following call instead of `ManagerCompare.CompareObjects`:

```cs
myResult = ((int)cellX.Value).CompareTo((int)cellY.Value);
```

But the best performance gain in this case is just 5%...

Sure I understand that our code uses unboxing because of storing value types as objects, but we can't avoid that. We need to provide the user with an array of objects that is populated dynamically from different sources.

The original version of this code was written in the era of .NET 1.x, but now we can rewrite it using more powerful tools from .NET 2.0 or higher, so any advices are welcome.

Comment: Sounds like you've already thought this through, so suggestions are unlikely to help much. Still ... "Our array can contain about a million rows" - is that a million rows or cells? How many cells? (Mostly due to curiosity.) Anyway, would it be feasible to change your type-agnostic "row map" into various type-specific row maps, one kind for int columns, one for decimal columns, etc.? That should remove the need to unbox the values being sorted.

Comment: @RenniePet, in the worst case our array has upto 1'500'000 rows and 75 columns. As for changing row map to a something type-specific, we can't do that as in the general case the array is sorted by several columns and our `IComparer.Compare` implementation takes this into account. I omitted its full implementation for brevity.

Comment: Hmmm, still, could the comparison method be made generic, with the generic types being the types of the type-specific row maps? So you'd need a CompareRows<T1>() and CompareRows<T1, T2>() and CompareRows<T1, T2, T3>() ... as many as the maximum number of columns that can be sorted on.

Comment: Use generic arrays/lists instead of object arrays. In a simple test I gained more than six times faster sort performance.

Comment: No, what I'm suggesting is that you write n different row map classes that implement a common interface, one for int, one for decimal, etc. Then you write x different CompareRow<....>() methods, where x is the maximum number of columns that can be sorted on simultaneously (surely not all 75?). Actually, now that I think about it, if the row map classes implement a common interface the CompareRows() methods probably do not need to be generic.

Comment: In fact, if the type-specific row map classes implement the same interface, then multiple comparison methods should not be necessary, just loop over the row map objects.

Comment: @RenniePet, I think it's not a good professional solution to write 75 versions of the row map sort algorithm. What if we'll need to have 76 columns tomorrow?

Comment: No, I'm saying one class for each TYPE of column. So if you have some int columns, some decimal columns, some string columns, and then one for those that aren't int/decimal/string. That's four classes.

Comment: @RenniePet, in our real-world app we do not know the type of array column because all what we have is an array of objects. We could guess the column type using the first item of every column, or something like that...

Comment: @RenniePet, note also that if we use `((int)cellX.Value).CompareTo((int)cellY.Value)` instead of our universal comparison algorithm for int's (an analogue of the generic approach, I think), we save just 20% of time.

Answer (score 1):

> The original version of this code was written in the era of .NET 1.x, but now we can rewrite it using >more powerful tools from .NET 2.0 or higher, so any advices are welcome.

One thing to keep in mind here (although it might not impact your particular scenario) is that in .NET 4.5 the implementation for Array.Sort has changed.

Coming back to your problem now. You say that you can't avoid storing the values as objects but that shouldn't prevent you from doing a bit or preprocessing. You could try the following:

- before sorting the array, loop through it once and cache all the information that you need. For instance you could create a new type which stores an IComparable reference + the results of GetType. Because you are using a comparison based sorting algorithm (at best O(n logn) ) this means that you only pay these costs once (which will at least remove some casts, method calls and comparisons in your compare method).
- the above should continue to increase your performance based on the lifetime of your array

Comment: I know that the Array.Sort implementation was changed in .NET 4.5, but we still need to use our code at least with .NET 4.0. As for your idea with caching required data, yes, it's a nice idea. I'll think how to try it in our complex code.

Comment: Sure. Let me know if it helps. Of course all I suggested is under the assumption that this is the only part of the system over which you have control. A better solution would probably be, like the others suggested, not storing your data like this.

Comment: We can't change the data store we should sort. And as I wrote, the main problem is not in the comparison but in how Array.Sort() moves the array items while sorting. And note that we apply Array.Sort not to the data itself but to the row map array, every item of which is a simple struct that consists of 3 integer values.

Comment: The approach with caching the IComparable data brings 13% performance improvement. However, this is a rough estimation made without the code related to type comparison. Note also that caching IComparable and Type bloats the source array a lot (in the worst case 3 object values instead of 1), which may be a serious issue for arrays with 1'000'000+ items. So I doubt whether we should go this way, but in any case I marked your answer as useful.